# What happened to the Close queue?

Tags: support

Somewhere in the neighborhood of 600 questions disappeared from the Close queue today.  Was there some kind of executive action to clear out certain patterns of questions (like anything older than X days)?  Just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pending [close votes older than 14 days were removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting).

Those hanging on were of the 600 you noticed vanish.

You're free to recast the close vote, which you weren't able to before if it failed to catch enough close vote velocity.